# surveymonkey How do you enter multiple survey_id values using the get_survey_details method?

Tags: surveymonkey

I want to add multiple survey_id values in the get_survey_details method but I keep getting an error message with everything I've tried. I've used comma separated values, replicating the structure for multiple entries, multiple values with a space delimiter -- but nothing has worked. See the error message below.

{
  "status": 3,
  "errmsg": "Invalid data detected in parameter 'survey_id'."
}

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it is not possible to request details for multiple surveys simultaneously using get_survey_details.  You will need to send separate requests for each survey.

Comment: Thanks for the update Ryan. This makes it difficult to create an automated process since the extract process will be by individual survey_id values instead of a batch of values. Are there any plans to add this functionality in the near future?

Comment: You should generally be caching the results for get_survey_details since the data returned by it will only change when the design of the survey changes. Use get_survey_list to request the data_modified for each survey and update the details only for those surveys which have been modified since last time you checked. Once you've gotten the latest survey details, store them in your database and cross reference any new data you retrieve from the API to your local copy.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I need multiple survey_id values (52824124, 52824167, 52824192, etc) and not just one by one. I would use get_survey_list to get the entire list of surveys but then I want to use this result set to get all of the details from get_survey_details.